# Displaying data from custom table

Tags: query, mysql

Just looking for a bit of advice on how to handle this:

In the past (many moons ago) when I did the occasional php/mysql work, it was relatively easy to pull/display data from a table using the table header in the "WHERE" query. (i.e. SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'column-name' = 'query').
The tables would have columns for each piece of information such as email, phone, address, etc.

I am currently working on a project using a table that was installed into the database by a plugin where I want to use some of that data in a different area of the site not related to the plugin.

Instead of a column for each type of information as above, this table has

- a user_id column which is linked to the users wordpress account
- user_id a meta_key column. This column has entries such as address, phone number, etc. (these would be the column names in my above example)
- a meta_value column. This column holds the data for each type of meta_key (the actual address, phone number, etc.)

What I am looking to do is get the value for each item for a particular user_id and pre-fill a form that is submitted.

So their User ID, Name and email are pulled from the users table of the WP database when they are logged in using the *wp_get_current_user()* function.
Once I have the User ID, I then want to display that user's address, phone number etc from the other table in my form but I'm stuck on the sql query

Something like:

```
global $wpdb;    
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid = $current_user->ID;

$table = $wpdb_>prefix . 'plugin-table';
```

I then want to select the user's address and phone number etc and display them as individual pieces of info, so:

```
$mobile
$address
$studentnumber
```

so that I can use them where needed

What would be the correct way to query the database to get the info I'm looking for?

Hope that all made sense...

Comment: anybody…? Do I need to explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

So, the following works:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $studentTable WHERE `user_id` = $uid AND `um_key` LIKE 'student_number' ");

foreach($result as $studentNumber){
    echo $studentNumber->um_value.'<br/>';
}
```

though I feel that 'foreach' is not really the correct syntax/terminology to be using?

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'your_table_name';

$results = $wpdb->get_results(

    "SELECT * FROM $table_name"

);

foreach($results as $row)
{

    echo $row->id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so maybe the above wasn't worded very well?

I have since made some progress as follows:

```
global $wpdb;    
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid = $current_user->ID;
$fname = $current_user->first_name . " " . $current_user->last_name;
$email = $current_user->user_email;

$studentTable = $wpdb->prefix.'um_metadata';


$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $studentTable WHERE `user_id` = $uid AND 'um_key' = 'student_number' ");

foreach($result as $studentNumber){
    echo $studentNumber->um_value;
}
```

Quick context:

- um_key column is the type of data (phone, address,
  etc.)
- um_value is the column with the information

If I remove `AND 'um_key' = 'student_number'` from the SQL query, the result will spit out all the rows that have the correct user_id, but I am only looking to output the specific row that has the um_key 'student_number'

Any help appreciated